# I have only one ssd but it appears like two seperate drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside windows but I quickly realized that I much prefer windows so I wanted to allocate the majority of my drive space to it. I shrinked my windows drive by 100 GB and booted from a USB to mess around with the G-Parted partitions a bit. I managed to put an extra 20 GB or so to root partition and an extra 80 GB or so to home partition. Below you will find a screenshot of how my partitions currently look like:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfyS6.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fUUx.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtrTz.png)
Even though my partitions look fine when I go to file manager to check out my space two separate drives appear. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkrD7.png) How can I merge them? Do files get stored in one drive or the other? Sorry I am just new to Ubuntu and in my first year studying cs and I am so confused, any help would be appreciated.

That's what appears when I run cat /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=6f8c3b18-4030-4f93-a577-b020eb65e9ac /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=6fe8a4b7-807b-400e-91d8-fd04d4cc29b1 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=6EC6-D90C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p8 during installation
UUID=89a98b40-c146-4953-a3a5-5c78b38d1972 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=1f1472b4-c452-4595-b10b-6c44b814c0d3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: 98 GB Volume is just your Windows partition, while Computer is Ubuntu's one.

Comment: @mathway Oh okay I see, why does it only say I have 42 GB left though? As you can see from the picture I posted it appears that I have a lot more space available on /home and /root

Comment: It's like it shows only the root space and not the space I added on home. Do my files still get saved in home partition or I have to up my root partition space?

Comment: Do you have /home mounted in /etc/fstab. Post this above, do not use screen shot. `cat /etc/fstab` If not you may be saving data in /home folder inside /. And then have to copy data to /home partition from folder first or you hide or lose data. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: I don't understand the discrepancy between the gparted screenshot, and the df-h output, e.g. /dev/nvme0np6 (/) size 40GiB according to gparted, size 119G according to `df` 1 GIB = 1.07374 GB

Comment: @oldfred I posted the output of cat /etc/fstab. Do I need to follow the intstructions from the link you sent me? And also should I do every single step since i already have a /home partition or should I start from somewhere specific?

Comment: No, you are showing /home mounted in fstab, so it is used. Most desktops do not need separate /boot, but that is ok, as long as you manage how full it gets. It used to be an issue as a default /boot was too small, but now not normally an issue. Separately you may want to add settings in fstab for SSD like noatime, but that is separate question/answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! So my real space for my files and downloads is the one displayed by the command df -h in /home?